# In Shiny, how to make tabs appear one at a time without javascript, etc

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to use a set of `if` and `else` statements to select which `tabsetPanel` to use.  The idea would be to have new tabs appear as the user performs prerequisite tasks.  What I created seems to try to do that, but the existing tabs get reloaded, resetting the state of the tab, and therefore removing the tab that was just added.  In my example, you can see the second tab flash into existence and then disappear.  How can I make the input in each tab persist upon recreation of the `tabsetPanel`?  I read a response to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25455154/navlistpanel-make-tabs-sequentially-active-in-shiny-app), but I am not familiar with javascript (or whatever code is inside `tags$script` in that answer), so I'd like a solution that requires only R code.

The app is [available on shinyapps](https://debarros.shinyapps.io/AppearingPanel1/).

The code is pasted below, and is also [available on github](https://github.com/debarros/AppearingPanel1).

## ui.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Subset data before analyzing"),
  sidebarPanel(),
  mainPanel(uiOutput("Panels"))
))
```

## server.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {  

  #This is the data
  d1 = data.frame(
    Student = c("Abe","Bill","Clare","Abe","Bill","Clare"),
    Class = c("ELA","ELA","ELA","Math","Math","Math"),
    Grade = c(71,72,73,74,75,76))

  # This pulls a list of unique names from the Student column of the data and creates a checklist
  output$StudentCheckList <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(d1)){return ()
    } else tagList(
      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "SelectedStudents", 
                         label = "Which students you like to select?", 
                         choices = unique(as.character(d1$Student)))
    )
  })

  #This pulls a list of unique names from the Class column of the data and creates a checklist
  output$ClassCheckList <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(d1)){return ()
    } else tagList(
      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "SelectedClasses", 
                         label = "Which classes would you like to select?", 
                         choices = unique(as.character(d1$Class)))
    )
  })

  # This generates the table of data subsetted by the checklist selections
  output$Summary = renderTable({
    if(is.null(d1)){return ()
    } else {
      d3 = d1[which(as.character(d1$Student) %in% input$SelectedStudents),]
      d3 = d3[which(as.character(d3$Class) %in% input$SelectedClasses),]
      return(d3)
    }
  })

    # These are the definitions for the individual panels
  p1 = reactive(tabPanel("Pick Students",uiOutput("StudentCheckList")))
  p2 = reactive(tabPanel("Pick Classes",uiOutput("ClassCheckList")))
  p3 = reactive(tabPanel("Summary",tableOutput("Summary")))

  # This generates the actual panel layout
  output$Panels = renderUI({
    tagList(
      if(is.null(d1)){return()
      } else if (length(input$SelectedStudents)==0){tabsetPanel(p1())
      } else if (length(input$SelectedClasses)==0){tabsetPanel(p1(),p2())
      } else tabsetPanel(p1(),p2(),p3())
      )
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem.  It involves a few components.

First, I had to create a new version of the `tabsetPanel` function (which I called `tabsetPanel2`.  It is essentially the same as `tabsetPanel` except that it drops any `tabPanel` objects that are NULL.  That way, any `tabPanel` objects that are not supposed to appear can be set to NULL, and the call to `tabsetPanel` doesn't have to change.

Second, I had to create reactive objects that held the selections made by the user on each widget that resides on a `tabPanel`, and set the `selected` parameter of the widget to to that reactive object.  That way, when `tabsetPanel2` is rebuilt, it loads the previously entered info.

Third, I had to create a reactive object to hold the name of the selected tab.  That way, when `tabsetPanel2` is rebuilt, it automatically goes to the tab the user was just on.

All of the code can be found in the github repository mentioned in the question.