# Shiny conditional navlist

Tags: r, shiny

Using R and Shiny, I am using the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25455154/navlistpanel-make-tabs-sequentially-active-in-shiny-app) as the basis of my code but will act as a good minimal reproducible example. But I would like my shiny app that uses a `navlistPanel` to change to the next `tabPanel` after the done button has been clicked, is this possible?

I think that using the `id` argument and referencing it using input$id as it mentions on the documentation might work...but do not know how this is done. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an observer expression connected to the action button.
Here is the code to be inserted in the `server` part of your minimal example:

```
observe({
  if (input$data_upload_done %% 2 == 0 ) {
     updateTabsetPanel(session, "mynavlist", selected = "Data Upload")
  } else {
     updateTabsetPanel(session, "mynavlist", selected = "Data Check")
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Can you please explain why it needs to use `x_even`?

Comment: You are right, it is not necessary. I edited it out.

Comment: Is the `%% 2 == 0` part of the code designed to so that it can be clicked more than once?

Comment: It is designed so that the action is triggered when the state value of the button [is even](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/shiny/docs/updateTabsetPanel). It can be clicked more than once if, for an unknown reason, the action is not properly triggered.