# R shiny Condition a tab in the navbar based on previous tabs condition

Tags: r, tabs, shiny, conditional-statements

I have the following reproducible code

```
Poly = data.frame(Strat = c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B"), long = c(174.5012, 174.5026, 174.5026, 174.5014,174.5012,174.5012 ,174.5020, 174.5020,174.5012,174.5012),lat = c(-35.84014, -35.84018, -35.84137,-35.84138,-35.84014,-35.84014,-35.84014,-35.84197,-35.84197,-35.84014))
Points = data.frame(long = c(174.5014 ,174.5017, 174.5021, 174.5023, 174.5020, 174.5017 ,174.5021 ,174.5017, 174.5021, 174.5019), lat = c(-35.84187, -35.84165, -35.84220 ,-35.84121, -35.84133, -35.84034, -35.84082, -35.84101, -35.84112, -35.84084))

library('leaflet')
library('shiny')


##### My take on Example 2
ui <- navbarPage(title = "navigation bar", 
tabPanel("Home", fluidPage(bootstrapPage(
checkboxInput("check_box", label = "Click me to continue", FALSE),
## Main text
mainPanel(
tags$div()
)

))),
tabPanel("View Data", 
   bootstrapPage(
    mainPanel(
    ),
    leafletOutput("map", width ="100%", height = "600px")
    )
)
)


server = function(input, output){

mymap <- reactive({
   leaflet() %>% addTiles(urlTemplate = "http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", attribution = NULL, layerId = NULL, group = NULL, options = tileOptions()) %>%  
   clearShapes() %>%
   clearMarkers() %>%      
   fitBounds(lng1 = 174.5042, lat1= -35.83814,lng2= 174.5001, lat2 = -35.8424) 
})

output$map <- renderLeaflet({
  mymap()      
})
myfun <- function(map) {
    print("adding points")
    map %>% clearShapes() %>%
    clearControls() %>% 
    clearMarkers() %>% 
    addCircles(lng = Points$long, lat = Points$lat, color = "blue",fillOpacity = 1,radius = 1)   
 }

AddStrataPoly <- function(map) {
  print("adding polygons")    
  for(i in 1:length(unique(Poly$Strat))) {
    map <- map %>% addPolygons(lng = Poly[Poly$Strat == unique(Poly$Strat)[i],]$long, lat = Poly[Poly$Strat == unique(Poly$Strat)[i],]$lat, layerId = unique(Poly$Strat)[i], color = 'gray60', options = list(fillOpacity = 0.1))
  } 
  map
}

observe({
  leafletProxy("map") %>% myfun() %>% AddStrataPoly() 
})
 }

  shinyApp(ui, server);
```

What I would like is to not allow users to click into the "View Data" tab unless they have clicked the check box? The tab will always exist ideally I would like to grey out the tab font as to indicate users they cannot click on it unless satisfying a condition (which will be documented) in this case a tick box.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25455154/navlistpanel-make-tabs-sequentially-active-in-shiny-app)

Comment: @SBista I am struggling to translate the Navlist solution to the NavbarPage in my example? would you be able to help. That is what I am after tho thanks for the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not an expert in js and css but I have managed to come up with a solution that works.

```
 ##Data
 Poly = data.frame(Strat = c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B"), long = c(174.5012, 174.5026, 174.5026, 174.5014,174.5012,174.5012 ,174.5020, 174.5020,174.5012,174.5012),lat = c(-35.84014, -35.84018, -35.84137,-35.84138,-35.84014,-35.84014,-35.84014,-35.84197,-35.84197,-35.84014))
 Points = data.frame(long = c(174.5014 ,174.5017, 174.5021, 174.5023, 174.5020, 174.5017 ,174.5021 ,174.5017, 174.5021, 174.5019), lat = c(-35.84187, -35.84165, -35.84220 ,-35.84121, -35.84133, -35.84034, -35.84082, -35.84101, -35.84112, -35.84084))

    library('leaflet')
    library('shiny')
    library(shinyjs)


    ##JS Code for enabling and diabling
    jscode <- "shinyjs.disabletab =function(name){
    $('ul li:has(a[data-value= \"Data\"])').addClass('disabled');

    }

    shinyjs.enabletab =function(name){
    $('ul li:has(a[data-value= \"Data\"])').removeClass('disabled');
    } "


    #UI
    ui <- navbarPage(title = "navigation bar", 

                     tabPanel("Home", fluidPage(bootstrapPage(
                       checkboxInput("check_box", label = "Click me to continue", FALSE),
                       ## Main text
                       mainPanel(
                         tags$div()
                       )

                     ))),

                     tabPanel(title = "View Data",
                              value = "Data",
                              bootstrapPage(
                                mainPanel(
                                ),
                                leafletOutput("map", width ="100%", height = "600px")
                              )
                     ),

                     #To use js code in the app
                     useShinyjs(),
                     extendShinyjs(text = jscode)
    )


    server = function(input, output, session){

      mymap <- reactive({
        leaflet() %>% addTiles(urlTemplate = "http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", attribution = NULL, layerId = NULL, group = NULL, options = tileOptions()) %>%  
          clearShapes() %>%
          clearMarkers() %>%      
          fitBounds(lng1 = 174.5042, lat1= -35.83814,lng2= 174.5001, lat2 = -35.8424) 
      })

      output$map <- renderLeaflet({
        mymap()      
      })
      myfun <- function(map) {
        print("adding points")
        map %>% clearShapes() %>%
          clearControls() %>% 
          clearMarkers() %>% 
          addCircles(lng = Points$long, lat = Points$lat, color = "blue",fillOpacity = 1,radius = 1)   
      }

      AddStrataPoly <- function(map) {
        print("adding polygons")    
        for(i in 1:length(unique(Poly$Strat))) {
          map <- map %>% addPolygons(lng = Poly[Poly$Strat == unique(Poly$Strat)[i],]$long, lat = Poly[Poly$Strat == unique(Poly$Strat)[i],]$lat, layerId = unique(Poly$Strat)[i], color = 'gray60', options = list(fillOpacity = 0.1))
        } 
        map
      }

      observe({
        leafletProxy("map") %>% myfun() %>% AddStrataPoly() 
      })


      observeEvent(input$check_box,{

        if(input$check_box){#If true enable, else disable
          js$enabletab("abc")
        }else{
          js$disabletab("abc")
        }

      })

    }

    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Hope it helps!

**[EDIT]:**
I know that there is an accepted answer to this question but still editing the answer so that it could be helpful for someone else later.

While posting the I answer did not realise that the click event exists even when the the navbar is disabled.

If the above js code is replaced with the one below the click event is removed and solution works as expected:

```
##JS Code for enabling and diabling
jscode <- "shinyjs.disabletab =function(name){
$('ul li:has(a[data-value= \"Data\"])').addClass('disabled');
$('.nav li.disabled a').prop('disabled',true)
}

shinyjs.enabletab =function(name){
$('.nav li.disabled a').prop('disabled',false)
$('ul li:has(a[data-value= \"Data\"])').removeClass('disabled');
} "
```

Answer (score 2):

Admittedly, the code below still lets a user to click into the "View Data" tab, but:

1. hides the content of this tab when "check_box" is empty
2. navigates automatically to "View Data" tab when "check_box" is selected

Maybe it would be enough.

No js or css is added.

```
Poly = data.frame(Strat = c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B"), long = c(174.5012, 174.5026, 174.5026, 174.5014,174.5012,174.5012 ,174.5020, 174.5020,174.5012,174.5012),lat = c(-35.84014, -35.84018, -35.84137,-35.84138,-35.84014,-35.84014,-35.84014,-35.84197,-35.84197,-35.84014))
Points = data.frame(long = c(174.5014 ,174.5017, 174.5021, 174.5023, 174.5020, 174.5017 ,174.5021 ,174.5017, 174.5021, 174.5019), lat = c(-35.84187, -35.84165, -35.84220 ,-35.84121, -35.84133, -35.84034, -35.84082, -35.84101, -35.84112, -35.84084))

library('leaflet')
library('shiny')


##### My take on Example 2
## the "id" needs to be added to navbarPage arguments
ui <- navbarPage(title = "navigation bar", id = "navigation", selected = "Home",
                 tabPanel("Home", fluidPage(bootstrapPage(
                   checkboxInput("check_box", label = "Click me to continue", FALSE),
                   ## Main text
                   mainPanel(
                     tags$div()
                   )         
                 ))),
                 tabPanel("View Data",

                          ## the content of "View Data" tabPanel is wrapped into conditionalPanel 
                          ## what hides the map until "check_box" is marked
                          conditionalPanel(condition = "input.check_box == 1",
                                           bootstrapPage(
                                             mainPanel(),
                                             leafletOutput("map", width ="100%", height = "600px")
                                           )
                          )
                 )
)

# argument "session" needs to be added
server = function(session, input, output){

  mymap <- reactive({
    leaflet() %>% addTiles(urlTemplate = "http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", attribution = NULL, layerId = NULL, group = NULL, options = tileOptions()) %>%  
      clearShapes() %>%
      clearMarkers() %>%      
      fitBounds(lng1 = 174.5042, lat1= -35.83814,lng2= 174.5001, lat2 = -35.8424) 
  })

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    mymap()      
  })
  myfun <- function(map) {
    print("adding points")
    map %>% clearShapes() %>%
      clearControls() %>% 
      clearMarkers() %>% 
      addCircles(lng = Points$long, lat = Points$lat, color = "blue",fillOpacity = 1,radius = 1)   
  }

  # the observer below navigates automatically to "View Data" when "check_box" is selected
  observe({
    if(input$check_box)
      updateTabsetPanel(session, inputId = "navigation", selected = "View Data")

  })

  AddStrataPoly <- function(map) {
    print("adding polygons")    
    for(i in 1:length(unique(Poly$Strat))) {
      map <- map %>% addPolygons(lng = Poly[Poly$Strat == unique(Poly$Strat)[i],]$long, lat = Poly[Poly$Strat == unique(Poly$Strat)[i],]$lat, layerId = unique(Poly$Strat)[i], color = 'gray60', options = list(fillOpacity = 0.1))
    } 
    map
  }

  observe({
    leafletProxy("map") %>% myfun() %>% AddStrataPoly() 
  })
}



shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I chose this is the answer because with the earlier answer you can still click on the tab and navigate to it.

Comment: @Cyrillm_44, realised that only after seeing your comment. Have edited my answer so that it could be useful for someone else who stumbles here later.